# Functor of points determined by finitely generated things?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, is $A$ is determined by to isomorphism by its functor of points $\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-alg}}(B,A)$ on finitely generated $k$-algebras $B$?

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$.  Then the contravariant functor

$$\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-sch}}(-,X): \textrm{$k$-sch} \rightarrow \textrm{set}$$

completely determines $X$ up to isomorphism of $k$-schemes.  If $X = \textrm{Spec } A$ is affine, I believe that the functor is completely determined by its values on *affine* $k$-schemes, that is spectra of $k$-algebras.  Thus $X$, or $A$, is completely determined up to isomorphism by the covariant functor

$$\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-alg}}(A,-) \rightarrow \textrm{set}$$

Suppose moreover that $X$ is of finite type over $k$, i.e. $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.  Can we say that $A$ is determined by the values of that covariant functor, *only allowing finitely generated $k$-algebras?*

If $B$ is an arbitrary $k$-algebra, then $B$ is the direct limit of its finitely generated $k$-subalgebras.  I was thinking we could do something like say that:

$$\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-alg}}(A,B)  = \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-alg}}(A,\varinjlim B_0) = \varinjlim \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{$k$-alg}}(A,B_0)$$

where $B_0$ runs through the finitely generated $k$-subalgebras of $B$.  I know that you can take direct limits in and out in the category of $k$-vector spaces if $A$ is finite dimensional, but since we are in the category of $k$-algebras and $A$ is probably not finite dimensional, this argument doesn't immediately carry over.

Comment: It would help of you started with a question. It is unclear what part of this post is the question.

Comment: Yes, all of this follows from the Yoneda lemma.